# Decoding a rank 5 tensor from tfrecords yields "CopyElementToLargerSlice Unhandled rank: 5"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to decode a sequence feature of type `tf.string()` with the length `FixedLenSequenceFeature` of shape (None, None, 120, 160, 7) in TensorFlow version 1.4.0. I am using padded batches and `tf.parse_single_sequence_example()` but when sampling batches from `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`, I get the following error:

```
Unimplemented: CopyElementToLargerSlice Unhandled rank: 5
```

and further:

```
[[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?,120,160,3], [?], [?], [?,?,3], [?,?,120,160,3], [?], [?], [?,?,?,120,160,7], [?,?,?,3], [?,?,?,3], [?,?,120,160]], output_types=[DT_INT16, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT16, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT16, DT_DOUBLE, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT16], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]
```

Handling rank 5 tensors in this way doesn't seem implemented. When can this be expected to be implemented?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, updating from TensorFlow `version 1.4.0` to `version 1.12.0` solved the issue.